# SQL , format all numbers to 2 decimal places (eg 20 to 20.00)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a data set with inconsistencies in a column with double values. Some are displayed as eg. 24.55, and others as 24.5 or 24. I want all values to be displayed to 2 decimals, so 24 should be 24.00, and 23.1 should be 23.10 etc. What code would work in this instance?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, such conversions are both database-specific and GUI-specific.  However, the database can convert the value to something with two decimal places by using `numeric`/`decimal` (those are equivalent):

```
select cast(value as numeric(10, 2))
```

The "2" is the two digits after the decimal place.  This should be displayed with two digits -- in any reasonable interface.

If you are using MySQL (as PHP suggests), you can use the `format()` function to accomplish this:

```
select format(value, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, how would I write this when selecting the table and column which is to be updated?

Comment: @mccull88 . . . You would add this logic in the `select`.  If you want to change the table, you would use `alter table` to change the type of the column.

Comment: I tried SELECT 'Col_Name' FROM 'Table_Name' format(value, 2) which is throwing an error. Do i need to add into the 'value'?

Comment: Data display tasks should always be targeted to frontend, because here are all the locale settings, additional operations etc. You'll lose the ability to work with numbers as numbers (arithmetic, for example) after they came from the database in "broken" format (as text).

Comment: Thank astentx, that makes sense.